# Bootstrap Double Gutters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When you create side by side div's with Bootstrap you have a gutter on both sides so in between you have double the space.  How do you avoid this?

```
<div class="col-lg-9">content here</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">content here</div>
```

This will give you a 15px gutter on the left and right, but a 30px space between the two divs.   How do you make it a 15px space?

Comment: set it manually in the divs. `<div class="col-lg-9" style="padding-right: 7.5px">content here</div>
<div class="col-lg-3" style="padding-left: 7.5px">content here</div>`

Comment: never do inline styles except it's inevitable

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap expects you to put your columns inside rows (inside containers).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-9">content here</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">content here</div>
</div>
```

The row has negative margins on the edges to eliminate the gutter on the sides of the outermost columns entirely.

It is designed this way to ensure that everything lines up, even if you nest column sets:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">Content</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">content here</div>
</div>
```

If you want to change the spacing between columns, Bootstrap expects you to do it by modifying the [`$spacing` SASS variable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/).

Comment: This does not solve the question about having a 30px space between the two divs

Comment: @RenatoDamas — You must have missed the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: I read it, but sorry, still does not answer the answer. That solution will modify the left and right padding for each column. My understanding of the question asked is that he wants a 15px| col1 |15px| col2 |15px and not 15px| col1 |30px| col2 |15px like he reported

Comment: Agree with renato!
I do not understand how this solves the problem.
I would expect a result of 15<div/>15<div/>15<div/>15<div/>15...

Comment: However, I think Quentins point about it was designed that way so everything lines up is quite valid, it is just that how it was designed to work is not the same as working as required by design.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the padding of column as **`7.5px`**, but also you have to increase the margin of row to **`-7.5px`** otherwise you will see the scroll.

> ***Note***: Try to use your parent class before **`.col-*`** otherwise it will affect to all other places where you have used the column classes

```css
.parent .col-xs-9,
.parent .col-xs-3 {
  padding: 0 7.5px;
}

.parent .row {
  margin: 0 -7.5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">content here</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about perfectly proportional sized columns, this can be a solution:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">content here</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pl-0">content here</div>
</div>
```

Adding the class `pl-0` basically removes the `15px` left padding from the second column allowing only a `15px` gap between first and second column.